# How to apply css inside the values of Label

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a `<label>` which contains multiple values like `

```
label = {Student[name] +  '(' + "20" + ')'}
```

Now how can I provide some `marginLeft: '2rem'` to the second value of label i.e.

`'(' + "20" + ')'` in the same label.

Comment: Put a span with a class for those values wherever you want marginLeft then add `marginLeft: '2rem'` to that resp class!

Comment: Are you aware of child selectors in CSS?
You can make use of n-th child and target the

Comment: You could add spans without classes around the values. And add margin to all childs. Then you can override the margin left of the first span, by setting first-of-type to margin-left 0;.

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle `label = {Student[name] +  ( <span style={{ marginLeft: '2rem' }}> 20</span> )}`, this is giving me `[object object]`, how to correct this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make it so the content of your label becomes something like:

```
label = '<span>' + {Student[name] +  '(' + "20" + ')' + '</span>'}
```

And then in your css do something like:

```
.my-wrapper > span {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.my-wrapper > span:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I think this should work. Replace .my-wrapper by any generic parent selector.

**Update:**
Or in a single statement:

```
.my-wrapper > span:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put `id`="label" for your label and in `css` writ

```html
 #label{margin-left:2rem}
```

Comment: This won't work because ID's should be unique per html document. The OP wants to add margin to each Student in the label, except from the first one. So there will be multiple elements.

An ID shouldn't be used, because it can't be unique in this case. And it shouldn't be necessary to add an ID in this case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using qvotaxon answer.

```
label = '<span class="myClz">' + {Student[name] +  '(' + "20" + ')' + '</span>'}

.myClz:not(:first-child) {
     margin-left: 2rem;
}
```